# How does Loki get this object?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, thor

In the beginning of Avengers, (2012) Loki has a sceptre which contains the Mind Stone.

In the end of the previous film (Thor), Loki fakes his death. He doesn't have it till that point.

1. Who gives him the Sceptre?
2. Why would anyone give up the Mind Stone?

**EDIT** 
I'm not sure what makes the answer so obvious here. The person who hands the sceptre wants the Tesseract, which means the person is after the space stone.
The same person gives Loki the Mind Stone to get the job done. Only Thanos could make a play like that, but we aren't shown Thanos giving this job to Loki here.

Comment: Did you watch the movie? He's given the Scepter at the start and he never knows that it's contains an Infinity Stone.

Comment: I was referring to the person who handed him the sceptre, did that person not know about the mind stone either? The movies are all a blur frankly.

Comment: @Paulie_D.. Watching the first scene in no way narrows down the answers to either of my questions.

Comment: @MovieMe .. most casual viewers don't look further into that opening scene, they are fine with an assumption that the Chitauris give Loki the sceptre.. and that's that. However.. the answer is accurate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At about 30 minutes into the film, Loki teleports to where the Chitauri leader is. At one point, he says "You question him, he who put the sceptre in your hand?"

Here you can see the scene for yourself:

And we know it's Thanos thanks to the post-credits scene:

Hope that answers who gave Loki the mind stone. As for why, I assume Thanos knew the Time Stone (Eye of Agamotto) and the Space Stone (Tesseract) were on Earth, so he decided to use Loki and the Chitauri to test Earth's defenses, so he could one day obtain them.

Comment: This.  In addition you see the same location in Guardians of the Galaxy called "Sanctuary" - where Ronan speaks to Thanos and the same Chitauri leader.

Comment: Thanks, this really removes the need to infer who it was.

Comment: @officialnoria Well, why should someone give up a stone to get another one, while he needs **all of the stones** to fulfill his quest.

Comment: @user71192 - Thanos is content merely to know where they are and ideally have them under his indirect control. He doesn't start collecting them (making himself a huge target) until he knows where they all are

Answer (score 7):

To answer in short:

1. Thanos gave it to him, along with command of the Chitauri army.
2. Thanos expected Loki to retrieve the Tesseract (which contained the Space Stone) and return it, along with the sceptre (Mind Stone) to him.  This was essentially risking one Infinity Stone to end up with two.

Loki likely didn't know what Thanos was actually after.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. is there a scene that shows that the shows that this was done by Thanos? Or is it an inference?

Comment: When Loki is mentally communing with Thanos' henchman, the henchman threatens Loki, mentioning that he is talking to "he who put the Sceptre in your hands".   Can't remember the henchman's name offhand.

Comment: Ah yes, the He references are Thanos because it's likely that he'd gamble one infinity stone to get one more. No one else seems to be aware of these stones. Definitely not the Chitauri.