# How did Thanos originally get the Mind Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe

After reading [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/98019/how-does-loki-get-this), I suddenly wondered if there is any existing material within the MCU that explains how Thanos came by the Mind Stone in order to then give it to Loki to try and gain the Space Stone.

Did he create the Sceptre and place the Mind Stone inside it, or did he locate it and it was already in there?

I'm aware that none of the movies themselves directly mention this, but I am wondering if the Avengers directors (Joss Whedon or the Russo brothers) have ever explained just how he came to be in possession of the first of the 6 Infinity Stones?

Or perhaps there was some preview comic released that addressed this?

Comment: After a simple google search: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aC3xYDDKEy4

Comment: @GustavoGabriel That video states within the first few minutes that the publishers backed off from claiming the book to be canon to the MCU?  As it's from a Youtube channel that's not affiliated with the MCU in any way, I wasn't entirely convinced of its accuracy

Comment: Just google "How did Thanos get the Mind Stone?", many answers from many sources will appear, from people who did the same research that we would do here to answer your question.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel is this site just for things that aren't mentioned anywhere else on the internet?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Of course not, but if the question is already answered elsewhere, does it make sense to ask the exact same question here? If with a simple google search you can find the answer you are looking for...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel: can you though? If the answer's a few minutes into some YouTube video, is that enough? If the answer's on Wikipedia, sure, but given that this is something that isn't covered in the movies, it seems on topic here.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I just used the youtube video as an example, just google "How did Thanos get the Mind Stone?" there are many results with many sources.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel: and if we describe some of them here, the community can vote up and down to indicate which are nonsense, and which are actually true.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Ok then, just a question, can I start adding questions here that already have been answered on other sites and sources, just because they are not in this website?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel: I think so! [The help section](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) doesn't currently say anything about not duplicating things that are already on the internet, and Stack Overflow was started in part with the intention getting useful programming information out of hard-to-search, hard-to-update forums, and into an environment like this where voting and editing can improve the information. I'm not super-familiar with the Movies.SE community; but for a definitive answer, you can ask on [the meta site](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @GustavoGabriel you can, but truth be told, if a question can be answered by Googling its title, it's probably a very poor question as basic research would have found the answer. "Shows no research" is one of the downvotes reasons listed in the down arrow tooltip, after all.

Comment: @Jenayah That's what I'm saying :)

Comment: Fair enough. I don't think the existing sources on the internet are particularly good or trustworthy, so I think there's value in a brief, clear, no-bull answer.

Comment: Indeed. Should probably have pinged @PaulD.Waite instead. In any case this getting off-topic, let's move that to [chat] if we are to continue that conversation :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 2018 novel [*Thanos: Titan Consumed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos:_Titan_Consumed) describes how Thanos originally obtained the Mind Stone:

> the Lorespeaker reveals that he is in possession of an Infinity Stone, the mind stone, and that he has waited for hundreds of years for someone to test it on. Thanos is tortured with the stone and tries with no avail to fight the Lorespeaker. At the last moment, Gamora and Nebula enter and kill the Lorespeaker, with Thanos gaining possession of the stone

However, [as reported on io9](https://io9.gizmodo.com/the-marvel-cinematic-universes-thanos-origin-will-be-re-1825242897?rev=1523896858028), although the novel was originally announced by its publisher as an official MCU tie-in, they were apparently contacted by Marvel shortly after and told that the novel is not, in fact, considered part of MCU canon.

So, officially, we don't yet know how Thanos got the Mind Stone.

---

In *Avengers: Endgame*, we

> see our heroes travel in time to various points where Infinity Stones existed, yet we *still* don't find out how Thanos first got the Mind Stone.

Comment: I couldn't find any actual statements from Marvel on this, so please, anyone, write your own answer with sources from the horse's mouth if you can find them.